# Memoria insuficiente en Microsoft Visual Basic para aplicaciones (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

Seguí el siguiente tutorial para pasar archivos csv a xlxs

1. Habilite un nuevo libro de trabajo, presione Alt + F11 llaves para abrir Microsoft Visual Basic para aplicaciones ventana y haga clic recuadro > Módulo
2. A continuación, pegue el código de macro debajo del Módulo secuencia de comandos y prensa F5 clave para ejecutar el código

#

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Al inicio me funcionó sin problemas, pero después de un día volví a abrir excel para hacer el mismo procedimiento y al presionar Alt+F11 me sale el error: Memoria insuficiente en Microsoft Visual Basic para aplicaciones.

[image: Error en excel]

Alguien sabe a qué se debe este error?

Comment: quiza podrias intentar: Archivo -> Opciones - Avanzadas. Busca la sección "Mostrar" y Activa la casilla : "Deshabilitar Aceleración Gráfica de Hardware." Has Clic en Aceptar e inicias nuevamente

Comment: Hice el procedimiento y sigo con el error, recuerda que el error sale justo cuando doy clic en el botón Visual Basic, osea que no puedo editar nada de código.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que el problema que tendrá será debido a un alto número de procesamiento de archivos. Pruebe a hacerlo creando un objeto en cada instancia y liberándolo.

```
Sub CSVtoXLS()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20170814
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xCSVFile As String
    Dim xWsheet As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.StatusBar = True
    xWsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Select a folder:"
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xCSVFile = Dir(xSPath & "*.csv")
    Do While xCSVFile <> ""
        Application.StatusBar = "Converting: " & xCSVFile
        Dim excel As excel.Application
        Dim workbook As excel.workbook
        Set excel = New excel.Application
        Set workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xSPath & xCSVFile)
        workbook.SaveAs Replace(xSPath & xCSVFile, ".csv", ".xlsx", vbTextCompare), xlWorkbookDefault
        workbook.Close
        Set excel = Nothing
        Windows(xWsheet).Activate
        xCSVFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Salu2,

Comment: El problema es que el error sale justo cuando doy clic en el botón Visual Basic, osea que no puedo editar nada de código.